# Sharpening a bound on $\zeta'(s)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I want to find an upper bound for $\zeta'(s)$ along a vertical line  $\Re(s)=b$, where $-1<b<0$.
One way to do this is using $$\frac{\zeta'(b+iT)}{\zeta(b+iT)}=O_b(\log T)$$ and $$\zeta(b+iT)=O_{b,\varepsilon}(T^{1/2-b+\varepsilon})$$ for each $\varepsilon>0$.
Multiplying them gives us $$\zeta'(b+iT)=O_{b,\varepsilon}(T^{1/2-b+\varepsilon}\log T)$$ as $T\rightarrow\infty$.  I want to know if there is a bound, for fixed $b$, that is sharper.

Comment: The functional equation expresses $\zeta'(b+iT)$
in terms of $\zeta(1-b-iT)$, $\zeta'(1-b-iT)$, and the complex Gamma function
and its derivative on the lines of real part $b$ and $1-b$.  If $-1<b<0$
then $1 < 1-b < 2$ so $\zeta(1-b-iT)$ and $\zeta'(1-b-iT)$ are bounded
and it's just a matter of the estimating the relevant Gamma and $\Gamma'$
factors.

Comment: Use the functional equation connecting $\zeta(b+iT)$ to $\zeta(1-b-iT)$ and differentiate.  Then use Stirling's formula.  This gives the bound $|\zeta^{\prime}(b+it)|= O_b(T^{1/2-b}\log T)$ (your expression seems to have a typo).  This is also best possible since $|\zeta(1-b-iT)|$ is bounded away from zero.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the typo, so I fixed that. Thanks for letting me know that this is the best possible estimate.

Comment: Here you can find some bounds http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~ramare/TME-EMT/Articles/Art06.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need me to go further, but if I were you I'd start out with the functional equation.  Take the derivative of both sides of the functional equation and you can derive:

$\frac{\zeta'(1-s)}{\zeta(1-s)} = log(2\pi)+\frac{\pi}{2}\tan(\frac{\pi s}{2}) - \psi(s)-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$.

Letting $s = 1-b-iT$, the left hand side will be exactly what you're looking at.

I am some what confused.  You say the vertical line where $Re(s)=b$ where $0<b<1$.  If it's a vertical line, then wouldn't $T$ vary and $b$ be held fixed?

If $T$ is allowed to vary (i.e. a vertical line), then wouldn't the answer depend on whether the line crosses the real axis?  I believe $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}s)$ blows up in magnitude when $b$ is really small in absolute value.

If $T$ is held fixed, and you allowed $b$ to vary, then believe the $\tan$ term is bounded since you'd be a fixed distance away from the problem point $b=0$.  If this is the case, Lucia is correct I believe.

Perhaps I'm wrong...it is awful late and my mind is worn out from all day of flying across the country.  I apologize if I made a mistake somewhere in my logic.

If I am wrong in my logic, could someone explain?  I'm very interested as well.